# Getting WebViewLinks with Google Drive

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-drive-api

I've just started trying to use the Google Drive API. Using the quickstart guide I set up the authentication, I can print a list of my files and I can even make copies. All that works great, however I'm having trouble trying to access data from a file on Drive. In particular, I'm trying to get a `WebViewLink`, however when I call `.get` I receive only a small dictionary that has barely any of the file's metadata. [The documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html#get) makes it look like all the data should just be there by default but it's not appearing. I couldn't find any way to flag for requesting any additional information.

```
credentials = get_credentials()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

results = service.files().list(fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
items = results.get('files', [])
if not items:
    print('No files found.')
else:
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:
        print(item['name'], item['id'])
        if "Target File" in item['name']:
            d = service.files().get(fileId=item['id']).execute()
            print(repr(d))
```

This is the output of the above code: (the formatting is my doing)

```
{u'mimeType': u'application/vnd.google-apps.document', 
 u'kind': u'drive#file',
 u'id': u'1VO9cC8mGM67onVYx3_2f-SYzLJPR4_LteQzILdWJgDE',
 u'name': u'Fix TVP Licence Issues'}
```

For anyone confused about the code there is some missing that's just the basic `get_credentials` function from the API's [quickstart page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) and some constants and imports. For completeness, here's all that stuff, unmodified in my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Drive API Python Quickstart'

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'drive-python-quickstart.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials
```

So what's missing, how can I get the API to return all that extra meta data that's just not appearing right now?

Comment: do you know if its possible to specify that webViewLink should return the view link and not the edit link? is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are very close. With the newer version of the [Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/), to retrieve other metadata properties, you will have to add the `fields` parameter to specify additional properties to include in a partial response.

In your case,  since you are looking to retrieve the `WebViewLink`property your request should look something similar to this:

```
results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10,fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, webViewLink)").execute()
```

To display your items from the response:

```
for item in items:
            print('{0} {1} {2}'.format(item['name'], item['id'], item['webViewLink']))
```

I also suggest try it out with the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list#try-it) so you can view what additional metadata properties you would like to display on your response.

Good Luck and Hope this helps ! :)

Comment: Aha, exactly the problem. This is what I get for not reading the code I copied closely. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You explicitly request only the `id` and `name` fields in your files.list call. Add `webViewLink` to the list to `results = service.files().list(fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, webViewLink)").execute()`. To retrieval all metadata `files/*` should be used. For more information about this performance optimizations see [Working with partial resources](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/performance#partial) in the Google Drive docs.

Comment: But should the method "get" return all that metadata also? and in my case those attributes are empty, dont know why, even with the right permissions!

Comment: The API explorer at the [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) returns the metadata specified in the fields request parameter so you might run into a different issue, e.g., in my app the `auth/drive` scope seems to be sufficient while the API explorer requires more.

Comment: Well the fields were empty because i was not using the "fields" argument to fetch them, and it is required to specify which data to fetch.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a custom function to help with getting a sharable web link given a file/folder id. More information can be gotten [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eO-7RIMTjOA)

```
def get_webViewLink_by_id(spreadsheet_id):
    
  sharable_link_response = drive_service.files().get( fileId=spreadsheet_id, fields='webViewLink').execute()

  return(sharable_link_response['webViewLink'])

print(get_webViewLink_by_id(spreadsheet_id = '10Ik3qXK4wseva20lNGUKUTBzKoywaugi6XOmRUoP-4A'))
```