# Gather the webViewLink and webContentLink in Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get the `webContentLink` and the `webViewLink` of a Google Document. For the moment, my code looks like this :

```
http = decorator.http()
service = discovery.build("drive", "v2", http=http)
fields = "items(id,title,mimeType,webViewLink,webContentLink),nextLink,nextPageToken"
list = service.files().list(fields=fields).execute(http)
docs = [docs for docs in list["items"]
                if docs["mimeType"] == DOCS_MIMETYPE]
template_values = {
   'docs': docs,
}
```

The `id` and the `title` of the document are here but the `webViewLink` and `webContentLink` are both empty.

How can I get them properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be noted that the `webViewLink` property is only returned for public folders, and not the single files inside such folders. You can use that as the base url to construct links to your files.

To retrieve the `WebViewLink` property, your request should look like this:

```
results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10,fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, webViewLink)").execute()
```

Check these related SO questions:

- [Not receiving "webViewLink" in response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652364/not-receiving-webviewlink-in-response)
- [Getting WebViewLinks with Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35044036/getting-webviewlinks-with-google-drive)